# How to use JSON data from Array

Tags: php, json

I have this result from verified transaction:

```
 Array ( [status] => 1 [message] => OK [user_card_no] => 6037997445418040 [amount] => 10000 [refId] => 787225 )
```

this is the function:

```
include_once("functions.php");
$api_token = 'My_Api_Token';
$transId = $_POST['TransId'];
$result = verify($api_token,$transId);
$result = json_decode($result,true);
print_r($result);
```

I tried to echo each key and value with this way:

```
echo $result->status;
```

Here is my result:

> Notice: **Trying to get property 'status' of non-object in
>   /home/skyw3b/domains/sky7bet99.com/public_html/pay/verify.php on line
>   17**

Comment: Remove `true` from json_decode

Comment: if i remove true, I'll get this:
`stdClass Object ( [status] => 1 [message] => OK [user_card_no] => 6037997445418040 [amount] => 10000 [refId] => 787225 )`
how can i use this one?

Comment: You can use same echo $result->status;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see above `$result` is an Array and in PHP to get a key from array you have to use

```
$result['status']
```

as you have done with `$_POST['TransId'];`